# The characters of the irreducible representations of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be ﬁnite group of order $n$ with $s$ conjugacy classes and let $X_1, . . . ,X_s$ be the characters of the irreducible representations of $G$ over $C$. Prove that the sum $ \sum_{g\in G} X_i(g) X_j(g^{-1}) = 0$ when $i \ne j$ and it is equal to $n$ when $i=j$.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a character $\chi$ of a a finite group $G$ of order $n$, then 
$$\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) = n\dim V^G$$
where $V^G$ is the subspace of the corresponding representation $V$ that is fixed by $G$.

Let $\rho_i$ be the representation corresponding to $\chi_i$, and consider $\rho_i \otimes \rho_j^*$, the star denoting dual representation. The question then becomes:

- If $i \neq j$, then the space of $G$-fixed vectors in $\rho_i \otimes \rho_j*$ is dim 0.
- if $i = j$, then the space of $G$-fixed vectors in $\rho_i \otimes \rho_j^*$ is dim 1.

But $\rho_i \otimes \rho_j^*$ is just $Hom(\rho_j, \rho_i)$, and the space of $G$-fixed vectors is just $Hom_G (\rho_j, \rho_i)$. Schur's lemma then gives the conclusion.

Comment: Do you have a proof for the first fact that you used in your answer .... I see that it is widely used and I want to know it's proof .... thanks in advance.